# How to build a CNN model for MNIST fashion and test it with a another set of image from web?

Tags: python, image, neural-network

Importing the data and splitting it into 4 for test and train

```
x_train=x_train/255.0    
x_test=x_test/255.0
c_trainX = trainX.reshape(x_train.shape[0],28,28,1)#x_train.shape[0] = 60
model3 = Sequential() # type of DNN
model3.add(Conv2D(28, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape = (28,28,1)))  
model3.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model3.add(Flatten()) 
model3.add(Dense(200, activation="relu"))                
model3.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))         
model3.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
metrics=['accuracy'])

model3.fit(c_trainX, y_train, epochs=15)

model3.evaluate(c_testX, y_test)
[0.5343353748321533, 0.9064000248908997]---- This is my validation loss and 
accuracy
p = model3.predict(c_testX[:10])
USING ANOTHER INPUT

import urllib
from PIL import Image
%matplotlib inline
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://github.com/antony-joy/Data_sets/blob/main/tes.jpg?raw=true', 
"testing.jpg")
img = Image.open("testing.jpg")
numpyimgdata = np.asarray(img)    
import cv2
numpyimgdata=numpyimgdata/255
load_img_rz = np.array(Image.open("testing.jpg").resize((28,28)))
Image.fromarray(load_img_rz).save('r_kolala.jpeg')
print("After resizing:",load_img_rz.shape)
numpyimgdata_reshaped_grey = cv2.cvtColor(load_img_rz, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
your_new_array = np.expand_dims(numpyimgdata_reshaped_grey, axis=-1)
       numpyimgdata_reshaped = your_new_array.reshape(-1,28, 28, 1)     # this is done make the image in
                                                  # the same dimension of that of test and train data
image_predicted_array = model3.predict(numpyimgdata_reshaped)
test_pred = np.argmax(image_predicted_array, axis=1)     
print("predicted:",test_pred)
```

[5]

This is actually wrong. It should be printed as a trouser which is denoted by 1
cause in mnist dataset 5 is sandal
Label Description

- 0 T-shirt/top
- 1 Trouser
- 2 Pullover
- 3 Dress
- 4 Coat
- 5 Sandal
- 6 Shirt
- 7 Sneaker
- 8 Bag
- 9 Ankle boot

I tried with different images, I am getting number 5(sandals) when I try with some boot or canvas shoes even. What seems to be the actual mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is very simple. Here I will give you a complete implementation of your program. Please note that I may change the **model definition** and **image preprocessing** step. Ok, let get started.

#### Fashion MNIST

Get the data - Do some preprocessing - Visualize a sample.

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist   

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

x_train = tf.expand_dims(x_train, -1)     # from 28 x 28 to 28 x 28 x 1 
x_train = tf.divide(x_train, 255)         # Normalize 
y_train = tf.one_hot(y_train , depth=10)  # Make target One-Hot

x_test = tf.expand_dims(x_test, -1)       # from 28 x 28 to 28 x 28 x 1 
x_test = tf.divide(x_test, 255)           # Normalize
y_test = tf.one_hot(y_test , depth=10)    # Make target One-Hot
 
x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_test.shape
(TensorShape([60000, 28, 28, 1]),
 TensorShape([60000, 10]),
 TensorShape([10000, 28, 28, 1]),
 TensorShape([10000, 10]))
```

> **[BONUS]**: Look, these are `28` and grayscale images. Now, for any reason, if we want to resize and/or want to make it `RGB` (`3` channel), we can do that too. Check my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66353283/9215780).

Now, let's visualize one of a sample from our preprocessed data.

```
plt.imshow(x_train[0][:,:,0], cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Observe that, the main object right white and the background is black.

#### Model and Training

It's better to use pretrained weight I think. However, here is a toy model to train.

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape = (28,28,1)))  
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"))  
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"))  
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"))  
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())     
model.add(Dropout(0.5))         
model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))       
model.summary()

# Unlike you I use categorical_crossentropy
# as because I one_hot encoded my y_train and y_test
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=256, 
             epochs=15, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

```
....
....
epoch:15: loss: 0.4552 - accuracy: 0.8370 - val_loss: 0.4008 - val_accuracy: 0.8606
```

#### Prediction

Let's make some predictions on the web-searched samples. Before that, let's first define a function that will do the necessary preprocessing.

```
# a preprocess function 
def infer_prec(img, img_size):
    img = tf.expand_dims(img, -1)       # from 28 x 28 to 28 x 28 x 1 
    img = tf.divide(img, 255)           # normalize 
    img = tf.image.resize(img,          # resize acc to the input
             [img_size, img_size])
    img = tf.reshape(img,               # reshape to add batch dimension 
            [1, img_size, img_size, 1])
    return img
```

Ok, I **scrape** some **Fashion MNIST** looking similar data, let's open one of them.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('/content/a.jpg', 0)   # read image as gray scale    
print(img.shape)   # (300, 231)

plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
plt.show()

img = infer_prec(img, 28)  # call preprocess function 
print(img.shape)   # (1, 28, 28, 1)
```

[image]

All is good so far, except now we have a white background, which is not like our training sample on which our model is trained on. If I'm not wrong, all the samples of **Fashion MNIST** do have a black background. At this point, if we pass this sample to the model for prediction, it wouldn't make accurate or **close accurate** predictions.

When we make an **RGB** sample to **Grayscale**, the white pixel remains white and the other colorful pixel gets black. For our case to handle this, we can use the `bitwise_not` operation on the grayscale image before passing it to the model for prediction. This `bitwise_not` simply makes `0` to `1` and vice-versa.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('/content/a.jpg', 0)  # read image as gray scale    
img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)             # < ----- bitwise_not
print(img.shape)   # (300, 231)

plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
plt.show()

img = infer_prec(img, 28)  # call preprocess function 
print(img.shape)   # (1, 28, 28, 1)
```

[image]

Now, pass it to the model for predicted probabilities.

```
y_pred = model.predict(img)
y_pred  

array([[3.1869055e-03, 5.6372599e-05, 1.1225128e-01, 2.2242602e-02,
        7.7411497e-01, 5.8861728e-11, 8.7906137e-02, 6.2964287e-12,
        2.4166984e-04, 2.0408438e-08]], dtype=float32)
```

Now we can get the predicted label and compare [gt](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist#labels).

```
tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1).numpy() 
# array([4]) # Coat
```

Comment: OH thanks so much. its helps... but why does not code not working with the image I chose? It is far better than my model. But this does not truly predict pictures which i choose like examples https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLI1v2y135NqWm1ArgGruhThwGJOhkyNtOyw&usqp=CAU .   OR this    https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUOtsVaSi-pS6gSLaG7dYiQBwUtE2cNvsGRw&usqp=CAU     This is predicted as a bag  and coat respectively. Is it an issue with pictures in MNIST dataset??  with usage of CNN the model should work very well right?

Comment: Nope, for both images, the model is giving label 5 on your given two samples. But for the image that is already white background, I don't need to use `bitwise_not`. Run my code step by step, after training check with input data.

Comment: I tried it for the first sample its showing a bag[8] and for the second sample its a sandal[5].  so why is it showing a sandle?Its not predicting a shoe. is the issue with image with select to predict?  should it be of exact same model of MNIST fashion?

Comment: Did you use exactly what I answered? If so, would you please share a colab, so that I can give better look at where you stuck.

Comment: https://github.com/antony-joy/ML-MODELS/blob/main/cnn_CNN_MNIST%20FASHION.ipynb     hope this would help.... kindly do look into it

Comment: Do you require a colab file? Or github would do?

Comment: I see your notebook. No need to provide anything. Well, somehow you missed one of my points. In your notebook, cell [37], after loading the image `cv2('.jpg', 0)`, you should use `img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)`. Why? Because this jpg has a white background and we need to make it black.

Comment: And unlike this sample, the [other sample](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUOtsVaSi-pS6gSLaG7dYiQBwUtE2cNvsGRw&usqp=CAU) doesn't need to use `img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)`, why? because that image already comes with a black background.

Comment: Oh... yes my bad... sorry for troubling you regarding this... Thanks so much..now its more accurate to what I want                                                                                                        
 .. but still my doubt is that why is not predicting it as a sneaker[7 ]?

Comment: Yes, I agree that the model should give a more precise prediction. Currently, it gives close accurate predictions. To make it more precise, we need to train it more with data augmentation, tuning the hyper-parameter, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This actually helps me a lot!! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230191/discussion-between-antony-joy-and-m-innat).

Comment: M.innat, sorry to disturb you, can you look into a small query ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66693260/how-to-check-the-number-of-layers-in-a-neural-network-and-icrease-the-layers/66705121#66705121   I am not convinced by the answer given by Pradyut? is that right?  and also with usage of flatten does it not become 728[28 * 28] neurons in the input layer?